# "expression must have a constant value" while using ofstream

Tags: c++

I'm porting my game from GNU/Linux to Windows, using Visual C++.

Here is the problem:

```
std::stringstream sstm;

/// *working on stringstream*

const int size = sstm.str().size();
char buffer[size];

std::ofstream outfile("options", std::ofstream::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    buffer[i] = sstm.str().at(i);

outfile.write(buffer, size);

outfile.close();
```

It says: "expression must have a constant value" in declaration of buffer.

I have changed it to this:

```
std::vector<char>buffer(size);
```

And then VC says: "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const char *'" at outfile.write().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const int size = sstm.str().size();
char buffer[size];
```

`buffer` is a variable length array (VLA) here. That's illegal code per C++ standard - size of an array needs to be known at compile time. VLA'a are allowed in C99 and G++ allows it as an extension in C++.

`const int` can be a compile time constant if it's initialiized with a literal or by a ˙`constexpr`. In your case, it's not.

You're almost there - `vector<char>` is a proper way to do it. To pass it to `ostream::write()` you can say `buffer.data()` or `&buffer[0]`-

Answer (score 0):

You do know that `sstm.str()` creates a new string for each call? That will be a lot of strings, if the buffer is large.

You could get away with creating just one copy of the string:

```
std::stringstream sstm;

/// *working on stringstream*

std::string buffer = sstm.str();

std::ofstream outfile("options", std::ofstream::binary);

outfile.write(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());

outfile.close();
```